# split array at the element which matches regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

I have an array like:

```
var a= ['--test--','some','someOther','--ts','som','someOthe','--t','so','someOth']
```

I want to split this into 3 arrays ie,

```
['--test--','some','someOther']
['--ts','som','someOthe']
['--t','so','someOth']
```

So essentially I want to split it at the element which matches the condition `str.indexOf('--') > -1`

What's the most efficient way to do it?

`P.S`: I got it done with a gigantic code and weird logic, but I'm looking for a clean way to do this.

Comment: *What's the most efficient way to do it?* Normally, "efficient" refers to performance. Are you interested in performance specifically, or do you mean "compact" or "elegant" or "understandable" or something else?

Comment: I mean performance... since it's a js code and will be rendered on client side even byte size matters here. Thanks

Comment: "byte size" is not the same as "performance", although it's one element of performance. Normally, "performance" would be interpreted as meaning "execution performance". If that's what you're interested in, then the accepted answer is wrong, because `reduce` will be slower than a simple `for` loop,

Comment: thanks, can you please provide some reference for your claim? (for and reduce) and in my prev comment says "even byte size" which means I'm aware that there are other elements for performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A functional solution:

```js
var a = ['--test--', 'some', 'someOther', '--ts', 'som', 'someOthe', '--t', 'so', 'someOth'];

function split(array, pattern) {
  return array.reduce(function(result, element, index) {
    if (pattern.test(element) && index) {
      result.push([element]);
    } else {
      result[result.length - 1].push(element);
    }
    return result;
  }, [[]]);
}

console.log(split(a, /--/));
console.log(split([], /--/));
console.log(split(['some', '--test--'], /--/));
```

An alternative non-functional solution inspired by @seahorsepop:

```
function split(array, pattern) {
  var result = [], prev = 0, length = array.length;
  for (var i = 1; i < length; ++i) {
    if (pattern.test(array[i])) {
      result.push(array.slice(prev, i));
      prev = i;
    }
  }
  result.push(array.slice(prev, length));
  return result;
}
```

For a clever generator-based solution see @torazaburo's answer.

**Performance comparison:**

1. Functional: 10.7 seconds / 1000000 iterations / Chrome 48
2. For-loop: 10.5 seconds / 1000000 iterations / Chrome 48
3. Generator: 50 seconds / 1000000 iterations / Chrome 48

I recommend either the functional or for-loop approach, depending on your preferences.

Comment: thank you, simple and generalized version

Comment: Please don't down vote answers without explanation

Comment: @NishanthMatha Actually, there's no obligation whatsoever to explain a downvote (although I am not the downvoter in this particular case). Asking for an explanation is usually a waste of time. If the downvoter wanted to give an explanation, he would already have done so.

Comment: What about the updated version of my for loop in my post? Also what do you use to test the performance?

Comment: @seahorsepip I averaged execution time for the given array `a` over three test runs with 1000000 iterations each. Both our loops have about the same performance.

Comment: I tried using the following tester:http://pastebin.com/HEyfNnrU, and that resulted in the following: ``yourFunc: 3227.984ms, myfunc: 1667.835ms`` which is a big difference, am I doing anything wrong or?

Comment: @seahorsepip That is because you have to test either with both using regex (which I use since OP tagged this question 'regex') or indexOf(). I tested your loop with regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generator-based solution, somewhat reminiscent of @anubhava's:

```
function *partition(array) {
  let tmp = [], i = 0;

  for (const e of array) {
    if (i++ && e.indexOf('--') >= 0) yield tmp, tmp = []; 
    tmp.push(e);
  }

  yield tmp;
}

console.log(...partition(['--test--','some','someOther','--ts','som','someOthe','--t','so','someOth']));
```

We can also generalize the logic for when a new bucket should start, by passing in a function:

```
function makePartitioner(startNew) {
  return function *(array) {
    let tmp = [], i = 0;

    for (const e of array) {
      if (i++ && startNew(e)) yield tmp, tmp = [];
      tmp.push(e);
    }

    yield tmp;
  };
}

var partitioner = makePartitioner(e => e.indexOf('--') >= 0);
console.log(...partitioner(['--a, 'b', '--c']));
```

The generator approach has the advantages that:

1. You can pass in any iterable, not just an array.
2. It can handle streams of input, even infinite ones.

Comment: thanks for pointing an other way, will take a closer look into `generator` functions

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this using `forEach`:

```js
var a= ['--test--','some','someOther','--ts','som','someOthe','--t','so','someOth']
    
var arr=[];
var tmp=[];
    
a.forEach(function(e) {
   if (e.indexOf('--') == 0) {
      if (tmp.length>0)
         arr.push(tmp)
      tmp=[]
   }
   tmp.push(e);
});
arr.push(tmp);

document.writeln('<pre>' + arr.join('\n') + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Please don't down vote answers without explanation!

Comment: Any particular reason for using `map` for side effects instead of its result?

Comment: Yes that's right `forEach` is better instead of `map` (edited)

Answer (score -1):

@le_m has posted a much nicer generalization of this code.

```js
var a = ['--test--', 'some', 'someOther', '--ts', 'som', 'someOthe', '--t', 'so', 'someOth']

var result = a.reduce((prev, curr, idx) => {
  if (!idx || curr.startsWith("--")) {
    prev.push([curr])
  } else {
    prev.push(prev.pop().concat(curr))
  }
  return prev;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is as best as it get's @le_m ans generalizes it and makes it useful for broader audiences.. so accept that. But, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: Please don't down vote answers without explanation

Comment: @NishanthMatha I agree.

Answer (score -1):

Modified the original code since it didn't work in all cases.

Edit2: back to a single for loop :P

```
function split(array, pattern) {
    var result = [];
    for (var x = 0, y = 0; x <= array.length; x++) {
        if((x < array.length ? array[x].indexOf(pattern) > -1 : true) && x > y) {
            result.push(a.slice(y, x));
            y = x;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var a = ["tes--t", "some", "someOther", "--ts", "som", "someOthe", "--t", "so", "someOth--"];

console.log(split(a, "--"));
```

Comment: Downvote for a proper answer? What's wrong with a for loop these days?

Comment: All the answers were downvoted for some strange reasons

Comment: Fails if the first entry of a does not contain the pattern "--".

Comment: With all respect @le_m, that was never part of the challenge. Your solution is probably the best here, you shouldn't go knocking on someone else's that "does the job" -- Particularly since this isn't "real" code.

Comment: I did not downvote anyone here, apart from an already removed answer that was plain wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup about the limitation, updating the code.

Comment: @le_m Should work properly now.

Comment: I liked your original code, it seemed very performant. What about
`var result = [], prev = 0;

for (var i = 1, length = a.length; i < length; ++i) {
  if (a[i].indexOf("--") > -1) {
    result.push(a.slice(prev, i));
    prev = i;
  }
}
result.push(a.slice(prev, length));` ? Saves you the reverse() call at the end.

Comment: @le_m Good idea about the ``length`` variable inside the for loop, I'd never thought of that. Trying to see if it's possible to stay inside the for loop and avoid the need for variables like ``prev``.

Comment: @le_m Somehow got it working inside the for loop itself ^^, updated my code in my answer.